# Rearranging property settings order in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings

Is it possible in Visual Studio 2010 to rearrange the order of the settings (in the Project/Properties of the project) and then Settings tab.

I only can find the add, delete and edit options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort ascending or descending by clicking the "Name" label at the top of the column for the setting names.  Otherwise, no.  I wouldn't think order is terribly relevant on the settings screen.  That said, you can name your settings carefully to make it easier to navigate the list if you have a lot of settings entries.

Comment: Thanks, not terribly relevant, would be nice though but now I will just rename them so at least they are grouped somehow. It would be nice if I could set my own order tough. Currently I have only 20 settings, but I think it will be hundreds later.

Comment: I know what you're saying; I have an app with 100+ settings, so it's nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

You can rearrange your settings manually.
Follow this link - http://ppe.blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/27/change-the-order-of-your-application-settings-vstipproj0024.aspx